# How to set Firebase rules to allow only unique keys to be created but allow update

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just started to use Firebase and migrated off of Parse by Facebook. The security rules are a little foreign to me. I need to have "posts" where users are allowed to create their own "link" to access the post.

For example, it would be like

```
domain.com/post/usercreatedstring
```

I am using the "usercreatedstring" as the key to the object in Firebase. To enforce uniqueness, my rules have a

```
".validate":"!data.exists()"
```

The problem is that this would also lock out any updates to the child too. Is there any way I can allow only unique keys to be created and still allow updating?

I was thinking of using `.push()` but decided it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Dave, I think that in order to help you we'll need to better understand what shouldn't be allowed. How would we tell the difference between someone trying to post a non-unique link vs someone updating an existing link?

Answer (score 0):

firebase uses $add(example.newChild).. Sorry if thats less than what you are looking for but the way i use authorization with firebase, if you are still having issues,  i would a resolve on a state navigation with authorization required that says 
angular 1.5/2.0

```
resolve: {

currentAuth: function(authservice){
$requireAuth(example).then($state.go(example2))
     /* or $waitForAuth when controlling a $stateProvider 
*/
},
```

Comment: Im not really looking for authentication... I need is to be able to have security rules that only allows unique posts to be created an updating these posts.

Comment: Are you familiar with angularfire?